# Has anyone used Facebook Scribe? (the tool for logging everything)

Tags: c++, facebook, logging, scribe-server

How does it work? (Explain it in terms of server, writes, GETs, values, whatever).

DOes it work with Win32 apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to explain:

1. There is an application, with thrift
   class/interface. When event that you
   want to log occures, you send
   message to the
2. Server, which collect logs from many
   sources (application, server logs,
   etc)
3. And then server decides what do
       do with it: generate visualization,
       send over tcp/ip, store in a file,
       nfs, hdfs, you decide.
4. Server and client can be the same
   app or machine, or this log data can
   be sent from client over internet.

Definitely works with win32 apps.

Answer (score 4):

It Works Great.
We're using Scribe to test some message processing.
We're sending Apache logs with Scribe. (Under Ubuntu)